# Java Reflection to read inner class values

Tags: java, gson

I have created a java class something like below:

```
public class TopNode {
  public Child1 c1;
  public Child2 c2;

public static class Child1 {
  public String s1;
  public String s2;
  }

public static class Child2 {
  public String s3;
  public String s4;
  }
}
```

This is class is used to read the JSON response using Gson. Something like below:

```
static Class<?> readJson(Class<?> obj) throws Exception {
Gson gson = new Gson();
.....
.....
return gson.fromJson(json, obj.getClass());
}
```

I am reading json response using above method and storing it into the object.

> TN_CONFIG

From this object, I am trying to access the inner class fields and their values, but getting null value only. Example:

```
....
....
Field f = TN_CONFIG.getClass().getDeclaredField("c1")
   .getType().getDeclaredField("s1");
System.out.println("S1: " + f.get(new TopNode.Child1());
....
```

Can someone help to find where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Are you using this [fromJson](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Class-) method?

Comment: Are you getting null values when inspecting TN_CONFIG with the debugger as well? Because your println is definately wrong as pointed out by i.bondarenko. You are printing the contents of a new empty node.

Comment: `f.get(new ....)` so you are getting the value from a new instance, mostly this must be null (if not being set in constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the problem, but lets try with a simpler sample:

```
class TopNode {
    public Child1 c1;

    public static class Child1 {
        public String s1;
    }
}
```

Assuming `TN_CONFIG` is an instance of `TopNode` <sub>(or any other class that has a `c1` which itself has a `s1`)</sub>, first we need to get the `c1` instance like in

```
Field fieldC1 = TN_CONFIG.getClass().getDeclaredField("c1");
Object child1 = fieldC1.get(TN_CONFIG);
```

and then we can can get the field value inside it

```
Field fieldS1 = fieldC1.getType().getDeclaredField("s1");
Object value = fieldS1.get(child1);
```

Note: this should also work if `Child1` is not a nested class.

Note2: `fieldC1.getType()` can be replaced by `child1.getClass()`

Answer (score 3):

I think you have issue in reflection code. 
You get value from new "empty" Child1  `f.get(new TopNode.Child1())`

Have a look at the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Child1 c1 = new Child1("value1", "value2");
    TopNode node = new TopNode(c1, new Child2("value3", "value4"));
    Field f = node.getClass().getDeclaredField("c1")
            .getType().getDeclaredField("s1");
    System.out.println("S1: " + f.get(c1));
}
```

Output:

`S1: value1`

Update, could you try follwing code to get the value:

```
    Field fieldC1 = TN_CONFIG.getClass().getDeclaredField("c1");
    Object objectC1 = fieldC1.get(TN_CONFIG);
    Field fieldS1 = objectC1.getClass().getDeclaredField("s1");
    Object valueS1 = fieldS1.get(objectC1);
    System.out.println("Value S1 = " +  valueS1);
```

Comment: nice catch there

Comment: I tried something like `f.get(TN_CONFIG.getClass().getDeclaredField("c1").getType())`, and `getClass()` too, but getting  **IllegalArgumentException**

Comment: My **TN_CONFIG** object has some values after loading JSON values into it and I'm able to print values if I try something like `TN_CONFIG.c1.s1`

Comment: @zeal and why do you not use something like `TN_CONFIG.c1.s1`?

Comment: In my original code, I have 5 inner classes and around 25 fields defined for now. So I wanna write value fetch function dynamically using reflections. Meaning: `c1` and `s1` in above line can be updated dynamically based on some parameters.

Comment: @zeal Could you try code from update in the answer?